# Reac component is not beeing exported

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm just trying to start a new website but not being successful at it. For some reason, I get this error `Module not found: Can't resolve './pages' in '/Users/joanaleitaooliveira/repos/web-project/src'`. Here you can see the App.js file and the about page file. All the other pages are the same.

I've also tried `./src/pages/About/index.jsx` but got the same result. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]
[image]

Comment: `index.js` not `index.jsx`

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the problem is due to the ***path mentioned in import statement*** not getting resolved.

Problem can be fixed by using the complete path to the component in the import statement.

**Working example:**

```
import Home from "./pages/Home"
import About from "./pages/About"
import Contact from "./pages/Contact"
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an `index.js` file in `pages` that exports all these components if you want to import through `./pages`.

Comment: export About from './About';